# Multiple consumer and producers, how do I unlock consumer thread

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I am trying to make a multiple producer and consumer program. The producers produce random numbers and insert them into a shared queue(shared memory) and the consumers print out the numbers. The user calls the program with the following arguments: number of producer threads, number of consumer threads and the size of the shared data.

Right now it just produces one producer(it seems) and just stops. I wanted to see if I can get some help figuring out how to unlock the consumers.

This is the Queue header

```
class SyncQueue
{
 public:
    SyncQueue(int sizeMax);
    void enqueue(int value);
    int dequeue();

 private:
   int MaxSize, front, rear, itemcounter;
   std::vector<int> QueueElements;
   std::mutex mutex;

   //Condition variables for full and empty checks
   std::condition_variable NotFull;
   std::condition_variable NotEmpty;
  };
```

This is the Queue functions

```
SyncQueue::SyncQueue(int sizeMax)
{
  front = 0;
  rear = 0;
  MaxSize = sizeMax;
  itemcounter = 0;
  QueueElements.reserve(MaxSize);
  }
void SyncQueue::enqueue(int value)
{
   std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
   NotFull.wait(lock , [this](){return itemcounter != MaxSize; });
   QueueElements[rear] = value;
   rear = (rear + 1) % MaxSize;
   ++itemcounter;
   NotEmpty.notify_all();
  }

 int SyncQueue::dequeue()
 {

   std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
   NotEmpty.wait(lock, [this](){return itemcounter != 0; });
   int number = QueueElements[front];
   front = (front + 1) % MaxSize;
   --itemcounter; 
   NotFull.notify_all();
   return number;
  }
```

This is main where I create the threads

```
std::vector<std::thread> producers(producerThreadCount);
std::vector<std::thread> consumers(consumerThreadCount);

SyncQueue queue(size);

//Build producer threads
for (int i = 0; i < producerThreadCount; i++)
 {
  producers[i] = std::thread(produceThread, i,std::ref(ProducerMutex), std::ref(queue), 200);
 }

//Build consumers
for (int i = 0; i < consumerThreadCount; i++)
{
  consumers[i] = std::thread(consumeThread, i, std::ref(ConsumerMutex), std::ref(queue), 400);
}
```

These are the produce and consume threads

```
void produceThread(int threadId, std::mutex &ProducerMutex, SyncQueue   &sharedQueue, int time)
{
  while (true)
   {
     int value = RandomNumberGenerator(std::ref(ProducerMutex));
     sharedQueue.enqueue(value);
     std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(time));
   }

 }
void consumeThread(int threadId, std::mutex &ConsumerMutex, SyncQueue &sharedQueue, int time)
{
  while (true)
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(ConsumerMutex);
    int value; 
    std::cout << "Thread:" << threadId << " consumes:"  <<sharedQueue.dequeue() << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(time));
  }
 }
```

Comment: `vector::reserve()` doesn't change the size of the vector (only capacity). All your index accesses are out of bounds and exhibit undefined behavior.

Comment: What does `RandomNumberGenerator` look like, and why does it need a mutex? Come to think of it, what do you feel you need `ProducerMutex` and `ConsumerMutex` for? They are already being synchronized via the shared thread-safe queue - isn't that the whole point of the exercise?